# Condition is returning true even if its not (Android)

Tags: java, android

My problem is really simple but I can't find the solution.

I have integer variable named ***points*** which currently have value of 684. I'm making some kind of shop for a game where you can buy stuff with those points and if you don't have enough points you can't buy specific item and the item is colored gray.

The problem is that when I check if number of points is smaller than the number that is required to buy a specific item the result is always true even if its false.

```
if (points < 500) {
    txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.rgb(185, 185, 185));
    txtPrice.setTextColor(Color.rgb(185, 185, 185));
}
```

I have double checked that points are integer type have the value greater than 500.

The only way I assign value to variable is like this:

```
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          points++;
          g_points.setText(String.valueOf(points));
     }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have another variable called `points` in that scope that may have another value?

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Perhaps you are `shadowing` your variable `points`

Comment: For sanity's sake, you should log the value of `points` just before the statement and see its value. It's likely being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis No, for debugging purposes I show value of `points` right before that condition and its 684

Comment: Have you checked the value in the debugger (using *inspect*)?

Comment: Can u show us the code to set a value on points variable?

Comment: Please show us the code otherwise we can only guess a possible solution. Also, try to comment you variable declaration and compile: it shouldn't of course, but if it does probably you have another points variable defined. Another test would be to rename that variable with a different name.

Comment: I'd guess that it's a threading issue. New thread comes in and updates `points` on some event, but the thread managing the colour change doesn't see it. Try adding some `synchronization` around `points` on some lock object when reading and writing.

Comment: if you are using `ListView` and this `if` is inside `getView()` then make sure to handle `else` condition. `if` condition might not be always `true` but in `ListView`, rows get recycled and reused and you can easily get into situation where all items will be grayed out and you will think that `if` condition is always true.

Comment: Please print some log inside `if` condition just to make sure that your claim of `if` being always true is right. As I think you are judging it by just looking at grayed color and you coloring code might be buggy and items get grayed from some other reason but not because of this `if`.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh It is inside of getView(). I added else condition but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: Believe me issue is still inside your `getView()`. Please share the code of your `getView()` method. And **ALWAYS** give full context while asking a question. I can see everyone is guessing and trying to help you but if you would have shared this info then it would have been lot easier. Anyways please share your full/stripped down `getView()` method and related stuff.